# How to update Sprite position quickly with Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, simulator

I was recently working on building a simulation tool with Pygame. For this simulator, I have displayed a field and a robot traversing it. The way the simulator works is by inputting a list of `Pose2D` (coordinate) objects into the main loop and the robot would render itself at the new position with each iteration of the loop. The robot has to follow some paths which are only lines up to this point but will soon be expanded to splines as well. In order to follow these lines, I take the distance between the points, get the distance and the slope and divide the distance by a step size or update size for each line. The step size is how many times the robot will update its position while following the path. What I have noticed is that more updates slow down the whole window and cause the robot to slowly move across the field compared to have a smaller update size where it moves somewhat faster.  However, I have a feeling this method is very inefficient for smooth motions and since Pygame is somewhat hardware dependent, it would require tuning on everyone's system in order to run at the same fps or to update the robot at the same speed. Is there a way to normalize the system and improve the rendering speed while updating at a pretty good speed?
You can see the list being produced in [trajectory.py](https://github.com/Alpheron/Simulator/blob/master/visualizer/utilities/trajectory.py) and it being passed into the [main.py](https://github.com/Alpheron/Simulator/blob/master/visualizer/main.py) here. Feel free to go through the repository for any other suggestions you may have. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Your links to your code do not work.   Normally you gear timing with your frame rate.  Movement is also multipled by the elapsed time since the last frame update.  Pygame tutorials explain the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for this problem, the current setup of the code ends up becoming heavily dependent on the cycle-time of the CPU. In order to fix this, a delta-time variable should be multiplied by the velocity, and then should be added to the current coordinate position of the sprite.